# INDEX-MATCH All values, and concatenate/textjoin all matching values into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data:

[image]

Columns A thru D have the data set.
In the bottom half of the image, each "Code" and "Title" are listed only once, and the "Phase" column displays all the "Points" under the respective "Code" value. The Index-match for Phase and Code value only return the first matching Code value; I would like to insert a formula to automatically concatenate all the matching values and list them as shown in the image. Please help!

Comment: Is is the Abnormal not filled with `11, 12, 13, 14`?

Comment: My bad. It's supposed to be 11,12,13,14. I typed in the expected result; need a way to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the new array formulas in excel you can drop this equation in your cell for `Phase 1, Code 50-100, Title General` and drag down and to right as needed

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($C$1:$C$9,($B$1:$B$9=$B13)*($D$1:$D$9=C$12)*($A$1:$A$9=$A13),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately my excel does not have the textjoin and filter functions. Is there any way to concatenate based on the filtered values? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to do this otherwise - srry